# Invalid token error when trying to run integration tests on resource server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, integration-testing

I've been playing with this [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/resource-server/hello-security) that it's a simple resource server, I'm focusing on the integration tests since I want to implement the same on my own projects, but I'm trying to replace the tokens used on the integration tests with the ones that are generated from the Spring Authorization Server [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/authorization-server)

But when trying to replace the access tokens from the resource server sample with the tokens from the Spring Authorization Server sample it throws an `WWW-Authenticate:"Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1""`

I have replaced in the resource server sample the `MockWebServerPropertySource` JWKS "n" parameter with the Authorization Server sample own "n" parameter from the JWKS, but to no avail it still returns the same error.

Though the access token returned from the auth server sample and the orignal resource server token on the sample are a little bit different, though I don't know why it wouldn't work on the integration tests.

What I'm doing wrong and how do I replace the tokens from the integration test in the file `OAuth2ResourceServerApplicationITests` to add my own and work properly?

Spring Authorization Server token from sample:

```
eyJraWQiOiIwMjg2OWFlZC1hZjQwLTQ5MmEtYWFlYy1mMWZhMTI1N2UzZWUiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtZXNzYWdpbmctY2xpZW50IiwiYXVkIjoibWVzc2FnaW5nLWNsaWVudCIsIm5iZiI6MTY1NzExNDQ3OCwic2NvcGUiOlsibWVzc2FnZTpyZWFkIl0sImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo5MDAwIiwiZXhwIjoxNjU3MTE0Nzc4LCJpYXQiOjE2NTcxMTQ0Nzh9.IB57Lix9R6F7sL5Ai5hc0o8DbWfxzXCnCEp6HL8vYu3XyVYx-wPthb5vTX4vsoBrebFsgIBkO63At4R3mfpkJSZO72bA7o-OkJEW0-n3MQwTRDZssy7-wvCG_dnRJ2OPlInaXqOogzWRfETI-7l_Ey5pxjQoKUGzA0Omqm2OtdVzy5X7qUlsDJ3rYuI34092bTZJGP3O3RuXkuJaP6GSkhG4sForttj6aFMviXDPeNJ5zpuyWBMC5bRunvVhCo2NOkHoL8BMr1s8FLySrNCGbIEOE9lkZxDJ3LZ7pH3hsbFuhn7jXYlZ4J5sFEu6c0kHHVLU7ti4cm_7VYp7DRV91g
```

Original resource server sample token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzdWJqZWN0IiwiZXhwIjoyMTY0MjQ1NjQ4LCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwianRpIjoiY2I1ZGMwNDYtMDkyMi00ZGJmLWE5MzAtOGI2M2FhZTYzZjk2IiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoicmVhZGVyIiwic2NvcGUiOlsibWVzc2FnZTpyZWFkIl19.Pre2ksnMiOGYWQtuIgHB0i3uTnNzD0SMFM34iyQJHK5RLlSjge08s9qHdx6uv5cZ4gZm_cB1D6f4-fLx76bCblK6mVcabbR74w_eCdSBXNXuqG-HNrOYYmmx5iJtdwx5fXPmF8TyVzsq_LvRm_LN4lWNYquT4y36Tox6ZD3feYxXvHQ3XyZn9mVKnlzv-GCwkBohCR3yPow5uVmr04qh_al52VIwKMrvJBr44igr4fTZmzwRAZmQw5rZeyep0b4nsCjadNcndHtMtYKNVuG5zbDLsB7GGvilcI9TDDnUXtwthB_3iq32DAd9x8wJmJ5K8gmX6GjZFtYzKk_zEboXoQ
```

Comment: show us the tokens

Comment: I just added them

Comment: Besides thinking about keys, you will need to account for the fact that hard-coded tokens generated by SAS will expire. The token you provided is already expired. The tokens in the sample were intentionally generated to expire in 16 years.

Comment: Yes, that token was from when I gave it a try, but the moment I got the token from the SAS, I pasted it into the line and still said that it was invalid, they have the same scope, so I don't know what else could be wrong. And yes I will probably threw in a token a few years along the line when I get it working on my own resource server. Thanks